# How switching from HTTP to HTTPS automatically in Classic ASP

Tags: http, asp-classic

How to set such configuration,switch from HTTP to HTTPS automatically in *Classic ASP* ?

Answer (score 4):

Lets start

Create ForseSSL.asp file

And add this to it

```
<%

If Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_PORT")=80 Then

Dim strSecureURL

strSecureURL = "https://"

strSecureURL = strSecureURL & Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME")

strSecureURL = strSecureURL & Request.ServerVariables("URL")

Response.Redirect strSecureURL

End If

%>
```

And how to use it ?

Just add it to .asp page

<%@  language="VBScript" %>